# DocsGatherer - gathering and organizing fragmented documents

Tags: python, beginner, algorithm, python-3.x, windows

This script is used for gathering fragmented documents from your computer, and organizing them by extensions.

Here is the main things my algorithm does:

1. Search through path(s)
2. Stores documents' paths
3. Detects existing extensions
4. Copies documents by extension to categories in a directory created in the current working directory

```
# This is version 1.0 of DocsGatherer.
# DocsGatherer is an easy-to-use tool to help you gather your defragmented documents from all partitions, or a specific path.
# It can be used for backing your documnets up, or to take documents only from another computer, or device(e.g. an USB stick, etc.)
# It won't help you if you have your documents organized.
# It supports only common documents' formats.
# It is intended to run only on Windows machines.
# It is open-source, feel free to maniplate it to match your needs.
# Scripted by Mahmud Muhammad Naguib - www.facebook.com/naguib.regex

import sys
import re
import os
import shutil

pattern = r'\.{1}(docx|docm|doc|dotx|dotm|pdf|xps|rtf|txt|xml|odt|wps|accdb|mdb|adp|xlsx|xlsm|xls|xlsb|xltx|xltm|xlt|csv|prn|dif|ods|xlam|slk|pptx|pptm|ppt|potx|potm|pot|ppsx|ppsm)$'

num = 1

app_path = os.getcwd() + '\\DocsGatherer\\My Documents ' + str(num) # Specifies the directory to which documents will be copied.

matches = []  # Documents' paths.

extensions = []  # Documents' extensions.

existing_par = ['C:\\Users\\' + os.getlogin()] # Existing partitions.

sep = os.path.sep 

sys.argv.append('command')  # Prevents Python from causing an error.

user_path = sys.argv[1]  # The user's specific path.

usage = '''
               Command                    Usage
      _____________________________________________________________________

       [DocsGatherer.py -all]   gathers all of your documents.
       [DocsGatherer.py path]   gathers the documents in a specific path.'''

def os_checker():
    if not sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        print("Sorry! This machine doesn't run Windows.")
        sys.exit()


def partions_id():
    names = 'DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    for char in names:
        partition = char + ':\\'
        if os.path.exists(partition):
            existing_par.append(partition)


def search_par(partitions):
    for par_name in partitions:
        print('[*] Searching in ' + par_name + '...')
        print()
        for folder, subfolder, file in os.walk(par_name):
            for name in file:  # Looping through files' names.
                case = re.search(pattern, name)
                if case is not None:  # If a document is found, its path is stored.
                    exten = case.group().upper() # The extension.
                    doc_path = folder + sep + name
                    matches.append(doc_path)
                    if exten not in extensions and not extensions.count(exten) > 1:  # Stores existing extensions.
                        extensions.append(exten)


def make_cat():  # Makes categories for documents.
    for category in extensions:
        os.makedirs(app_path + sep + category)


def copy_doc():
    print('[*] Copying...' )
    print()
    for doc_path in matches:
        category = re.search(pattern, doc_path.split(sep)[-1]).group().upper() # Specifies categories.
        shutil.copy(doc_path, (app_path + sep + category))
    print('[*] Your documents have been successfully copied to: ' + '\n\n' + '   ' + app_path)


def view():
    if sys.argv[1] == '-all':
        search_par(existing_par)  # Searches in all partitions.

    elif os.path.exists(user_path):
        search_par(user_path.split())  # Searches in the user's specific path.

    else:
        print('                               ' + 'Invalid command! ' + '\n')
        print(usage)
        sys.exit()


def no_doc():
    if len(matches) == 0:
        print('[*] No documents have been found! ')
        sys.exit()



os_checker()
view()
while True:
    try:
        os.makedirs(app_path)
        break

    except FileExistsError:
        num += 1 # If My Documents * already exists, it will increase the number in it with 1.
        app_path = os.getcwd() + '\\DocsGatherer\\My Documents ' + str(num)
        continue                                                            
partions_id()
no_doc()
make_cat()
copy_doc()
```

Comment: What do you mean by a "defragmented" document? What is the difference to a "normal" document?

Comment: I'm sorry! I actually meant fragmented documents, which means documents that are not organized. Thank you! I will edit it.

Comment: There's a spelling mistake on line 5: `# It supports only comman documents' formats.`  **comman** should be *common*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few comments, in no particular order:

- **Be wary of OS-specific path handling.**

  Although you only support running on Windows for now, what if you want to run on other platforms later? You should code defensively, to make it as easy as possible to add that support later.

  For example, don't use the hard-coded string `.\DocsGatherer\My Documents` with explicit backslashes – use `os.path.join()` instead.
- **Use re.compile() to speed up your regex.**

  You define a regex at the top of the file, which is used many times in the body of `search_par()`.

  By compiling it, it gets cached as a regular expression object, which is more efficient. This is good practice if you’re going to use a regex multiple times.
- **Use the platform module for checking which system you’re on.**

  Rather than inspecting `sys.platform`, I think this check is more explicit:

  ```
  import platform
  assert platform.system() == "Windows"
  ```

  This makes the `os_checker()` a bit tidier. Speaking of that function, you should return a non-zero exit code to indicate that something went wrong with the script – exit code 0 implies that everything went fine, which it clearly didn’t in this case.

  (Ditto for `no_doc()` and `view()`)
- **Use POSIX usage strings.**

  There’s a standard for command-line usage strings called POSIX. Rather than the somewhat strange tabular usage string (which is a format I’ve never seen before), using POSIX gives a clear, well-defined standard that is easily understood.

  For your script, that gives the usage string:

  ```
  DocsGatherer

  Usage:
    docsgatherer --all
    docsgatherer <path>
    docsgatherer -h | --help
    docsgatherer --version
  ```

  I recommend looking at docopt, and in particular the [docopt author’s PyCon talk](https://youtu.be/pXhcPJK5cMc), for further advice in this area.
- This line is very nebulous:

  ```
  sys.argv.append('command')  # Prevents Python from causing an error.
  ```

  Your comment should be much more specific than this – what sort of error do you get if you don’t have this line? How does this fix it? How would I know if it’s not needed any more? And so on.
- **Wrap the mainline code in `if __name__ == '__main__': main()`.**

  Putting all the mainline code in a main function, and then wrapping it in this block, means it will only run if the script is invoked directly. It won’t run if, for example, some of the functions are imported into another script.

  This is a good way to make your code more reusable.
- **Don’t skimp on variable names.**

  Characters are cheap, and using full words like `make_categories()` or `search_partitions()` makes your code easier to read. It’s easy to see what `make_cat()` or `search_par()` mean if you’re looking at the definition, but it’s harder if it comes up in an unrelated piece of code.